# Javascript not working with adding variables together

Tags: javascript, html

Right so i have values in 3 dropdown boxes and there will be more (looking at adding about 20 dropdown boxes that add to give a final price for the item. Here is the code for the HTML.

```
<form id="myform1>
<p>Testing 1</p>
<select id="Test1">
<option value="24">Item one</option>
<option value="29">Item Two<option>
<!--I have the first box going to 20 items-->
</select>

<p>Testing 2</p>
<select id="Test2">
<option value="25">Item one</option>
<option value="100">Item Two<option>
<!--I have the second box going to 10 items-->
</select>

<p>Testing 3</p>
<select id="Test3">
<option value="24">Item one</option>
<option value="100">Item Two<option>
<!--I have the third box going to 10 items-->
</select>


</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Update</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Then i have my Javascript

```
function myFunction()
{
var a = document.getElementById("list1");
var A = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

var b = document.getElementById("list2");
var B = b.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

var c = document.getElementById("list3");
var C = c.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

var IntA = parseInt(A);
var IntB = parseInt(B);
var IntC = parseInt(C);

var x=IntB + IntA;
var y=x + IntC;
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
demoP.innerHTML= y;
}
```

My Problem is it only works if i take var c our completely and then take var y out and have it calculate to x. I have tryed many ways and am at a loss. Cheers

P.S. Java script is in a script tag at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You've used `a.selectedIndex` to get the selected item for all three elements. Change that to use `b.selectedIndex` and `c.selectedIndex` in the appropriate spots. Or you can just say `a.value`, `b.value` and `c.value` directly rather than going via the `options` collection.

Also the id attributes in your html don't match what you're using in your JS.

Fix those problems and it works, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WWdc/

P.S. It's a good idea to get in the habit of always passing the radix as the second parameter to `parseInt()`, like `IntA = parseInt(A, 10);` - otherwise if the input string has a leading `0` or leading `0x` it might (depending on browser, and presense of a `"use strict";` directive) be interpreted as octal or hexadecimal.

Comment: ... Or you can extract common functionality and stop repeating yourself!

Comment: cheers i noticed the names after i put it on lol i was just using it as a example will try the code now cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("list1");
    var A = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

    var b = document.getElementById("list2");
    var B = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value; //changed to var b

    var c = document.getElementById("list3");
    var C = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value; //changed to var c

    //...
}
```